# how to calculate max date of a date field of an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my node.js app I have the following array of objects, which includes a date field named REPORTEDDATE:

```
[ { INCIDENTNUMBER: 'INC000000000002',
    SUBMITTER: 'Chris',
    REPORTEDDATE: Mon May 09 2016 18:17:04 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    LASTRESOLVEDDATE: Mon May 09 2016 18:17:04 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    OWNERGROUP: 'ACME Help Desk',
    COMPANY: 'ACME Inc',
    CATEGORIZATIONTIER1: 'cat-1',
    CATEGORIZATIONTIER2: 'cat-2',
    CATEGORIZATIONTIER3: 'cat-3',
    RESOLUTIONCATEGORY: 'res-cat',
    RESOLUTIONCATEGORYTIER2: 'res-cat-2',
    RESOLUTIONCATEGORYTIER3: 'res-cat-3',
    REPORTEDSOURCE: 'Phone',
    DESCRIPTION: 'Some description',
    ID: 9 },
  { INCIDENTNUMBER: 'INC000000000002',
    SUBMITTER: 'Chris',
    REPORTEDDATE: Mon May 09 2016 18:17:09 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    LASTRESOLVEDDATE: Mon May 09 2016 18:17:09 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    OWNERGROUP: 'ACME Help Desk',
    COMPANY: 'ACME Inc',
    CATEGORIZATIONTIER1: 'cat-1',
    CATEGORIZATIONTIER2: 'cat-2',
    CATEGORIZATIONTIER3: 'cat-3',
    RESOLUTIONCATEGORY: 'res-cat',
    RESOLUTIONCATEGORYTIER2: 'res-cat-2',
    RESOLUTIONCATEGORYTIER3: 'res-cat-3',
    REPORTEDSOURCE: 'Phone',
    DESCRIPTION: 'Some description',
    ID: 10 } ]
```

Is there a way to determine the max date across the REPORTEDDATE fields of these objects?
I know - the better way of asking would be to describe what I have tried, but, with this format, I don't really know where to begin...

Comment: Please please reduce your code down to the minimal amount needed to show your issue.

Comment: Are the `REPORTEDDATE` properties strings or `Date` instances? I'm assuming the latter due to their not being quoted as strings in your example.

Comment: @Phil I don't think JSON supports a `Date` value type. It may just be a typo.

Comment: @4castle who said it was JSON? OP says they *"have the following array of objects"* If it were JSON, the keys would be quoted.

Comment: @Phil I agree. It's pretty strange, but I'm thinking since the OP accepted the answer which parses them as a string, they are probably strings. Or maybe they didn't notice that the answer did that.

Comment: @4castle passing a `Date` instance to `Date.parse()` kind-of works though it seems to truncate the milliseconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it quite simply with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), `Math.max`, and [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

```
var maxDate = new Date(arr.map(o => Date.parse(o.REPORTEDDATE))
                          .reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b)))
                          .toUTCString();
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc0pyf5a/2/)

Comment: Because you've mapped the array to only contain the dates, you don't need the `0` initial value for `reduce`.

Comment: @Phil I tested it, and it is necessary because otherwise `a` will have a string value on the first iteration.

Comment: Ah yup. I would have just mapped them to `Date` instances if they weren't already.

Comment: @Phil That makes much more sense. I've modified it to do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `REPORTEDDATE` is an actual `Date` instance and not a string, use a *reduce* operation

```
let maxDate = new Date(arrayOfObjects.reduce(
    (currentMaxDate, obj) => Math.max(currentMaxDate, obj.REPORTEDDATE), 0));
```

Note, `Math.max()` treats the dates as numbers via `Date.prototype.valueOf()` which returns the date's timestamp. This is why the output from the reduce operation is wrapped in `new Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the Date class to parse the dates from strings into something that can be compared in a loop to find the maximum such as:

`var timestamp = new Date(array[0].REPORTEDDATE).getTime();`

Depending on the implementation of the Date class on your system you may find that you need to play with string to get it to parse properly or failing that you may need to use an external library or write code to get the date, months, minutes, hours, seconds etc and construct a Date object from those.

Comment: How does this answer the question of finding the max date?

Comment: It shows how to parse a date string using Javascript, assuming it is a string and not already a Date instance. Of course the comparison and loop or perhaps more sophisticated reduce operation are left to the reader...

Comment: Luckily, the date format given can be read by `new Date()` and `Date.parse()` :)